# How should I make a function to add new elements in a periodic table?

Tags: c, structure

I have a main menu in this program, which contains options for searching an element and adding elements. Please check this add function and let me know what correction should I make in this since it's not working properly. I also have to make an option for the user to go back to main menu after adding the element, how can I do that.

```
struct element {
  int atno;
  char name[20];
  char symbol[20];
  char mn[20];
  float bp;
  char state[20];
};

int n = 118, i = 0;
void add(struct element e[], int n);

int main() {
  struct element e[n];
  e[0].atno = 1;
  strcpy(e[0].name, "Hydrogen");
  strcpy(e[0].symbol, "H");
  strcpy(e[0].mn, "Metal");
  e[0].bp = -252.879;
  strcpy(e[0].state, "Gas");

  e[1].atno = 2;
  strcpy(e[1].name, "Helium");
  strcpy(e[1].symbol, "He");
  strcpy(e[1].mn, "Non-Metal");
  e[1].bp = -268.28;
  strcpy(e[1].state, "Gas");

  add(e, n);
}

void add(struct element e[], int n) {
  int t;
  int an[150];
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    an[i] = i;
  }
  printf("Enter the atomic number of the element you want to add: ");
  scanf("%d", &t);
  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    if (an[i] == t) {
      printf("The element already exists");
    } else {
      e[t - 1].atno = t;
      printf("Enter the Name:");
      scanf("%s", (e[t - 1].name));
      printf("Enter the Symbol:");
      scanf("%s", (e[t - 1].symbol));
      printf("Enter the Boiling Point:");
      scanf("%f", e[t - 1].bp);
      printf("Enter whether it is metal/non metal:");
      scanf("%s", (e[t - 1].mn));
      printf("Enter the state at room temperature:");
      scanf("%s", (e[t - 1].state));

      an[t] = t;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: In C use `char*` in structures in preference to fixed-length buffers. This avoids a lot of overflow problems, and also uses less memory than having each entry with the absolute maximum allocated at all times.

Comment: After looking at the code I can't figure out what "not working properly" means.

Answer (score 0):

there are some mistakes

first with this loop:

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        an[i] = i;
    }
```

every input element will exist and so you could have no more elements.You have to compare `t` with `e[i].atno`.

you should use `&` in `scanf` for float. `scanf("%lf", e[t - 1].bp);` this should be `scanf("%lf", &e[t - 1].bp);` (it's not like strings)

finally ,since you are assigning `double vlaue` in main to your `bp` I convert float to double.

```
struct element {
    int atno;
    char name[20];
    char symbol[20];
    char mn[20];
    double bp;//warning since you have assigned double type to it in main
    char state[20];
};

int n = 118, i = 0;
void add(struct element e[], int n);

int main() {
    struct element e[n];
    e[0].atno = 1;
    strcpy(e[0].name, "Hydrogen");
    strcpy(e[0].symbol, "H");
    strcpy(e[0].mn, "Metal");
    e[0].bp = -252.879;
    strcpy(e[0].state, "Gas");

    e[1].atno = 2;
    strcpy(e[1].name, "Helium");
    strcpy(e[1].symbol, "He");
    strcpy(e[1].mn, "Non-Metal");
    e[1].bp = -268.28;
    strcpy(e[1].state, "Gas");

    add(e, n);
}

void add(struct element e[], int n)
{
    int t;
    int an[150];
  /*  for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        an[i] = i;
    }*///every element will exits with your method
    printf("Enter the atomic number of the element you want to add: ");
    scanf("%d", &t);
    int check = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (e[i].atno == t)
        {
            printf("The element already exists");
            check = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (check == 0)
    {
        e[t - 1].atno = t;
        printf("Enter the Name:");
        scanf("%s", (e[t - 1].name));
        printf("Enter the Symbol:");
        scanf("%s", (e[t - 1].symbol));
        printf("Enter the Boiling Point:");
        scanf("%lf", &e[t - 1].bp);
        printf("Enter whether it is metal/non metal:");
        scanf("%s", (e[t - 1].mn));
        printf("Enter the state at room temperature:");
        scanf("%s", (e[t - 1].state));
 //call menu function
    }

}
```